# PIG: How to pass relationship to Java UDF as argument?

Tags: java, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

My pig script needs to pass data to the java constructor:

```
UPCFIND = LOAD 'testdatabase.item' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() AS (upc:chararray,description:chararray); 
UPCDATA = FOREACH UPCFIND GENERATE upc,description;
DUMP UPCDATA;
//output:
(00001123456789," Table       ")
(00000123456789," PICTURE       ")
```

My UDF is:

```
loading = LOAD '/incoming/files/*' USING com.readingitems.loading.TheLoader(UPCDATA) as
 (upc:chararray, description:chararray,
```

Can I pass this **UPCDATA** to my UDF and if so, how would I get this into a hashmap where upc is the key and description is the value. Is this considered an arraylist or tuple? Thanks in advance!

Problem right now is passing this data into the java contructor:

```
UPCFIND = LOAD 'testdatabase.item' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() AS (upc:chararray,description:chararray);
UPCDATA = FOREACH UPCFIND GENERATE upc,description;
UPCDATA_SCALAR = GROUP UPCDATA ALL;

loading = LOAD 'files/incoming/*' USING com.readingitems.loading.TheLoader(UPCDATA_SCALAR)
```

Getting the error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionException: Undefined parameter : UPCDATA_SCALAR
```

**Dumping UPCDATA_SCALAR produces the correct results**

> The reason why I'm doing this is to load a hive table's data into a
>   Loader function that's parsing files. I need to compare data in the
>   files to the Hive table data in order to make changes and insert into
>   a new table.

My loader function starts with:

```
public class TheLoader extends LoadFunc {

    public TheLoader (DataBag item_master_stream) throws SQLException {
```

Comment: Based on the the gist I provided in the comments on my answer. Try: `loading = LOAD 'files/incoming/*' USING com.readingitems.loading.TheLoader(UPCDATA_SCALAR.UPCDATA.(upc,description))`

Comment: It's throwing 
`Failed to parse: <file pig2.pig, line 11, column 90>  mismatched input 'UPCDATA_SCALAR' expecting RIGHT_PAREN` For some reason it can't understand `UPCDATA_SCALAR`

Comment: So maybe I need to be using: `C = FOREACH A GENERATE BagToString(UPCDATA_SCALAR, '|');`

Comment: That could be a good test.  I wonder if it is because you can't pass scalars into a LoadFunc.

Comment: Ya  it just failed on that test as well humm....The reason why I'm doing this is to load a hive table's data into a Loader function that's parsing files. I need to compare data in the files to the Hive table data in order to make changes and insert into a new table.

Comment: Thanks for all the help btw, I'm new to PIG

Comment: To access the value of the scalar you need to do `UPCDATA_SCALAR.UPCDATA.(upc,description)` instead of `UPCDATA_SCALAR`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `UPCDATA` is a relationship.  In order to pass it into a function as an argument, you are going to have to [convert it into a scalar.](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#cast-relations) You can accomplish this with:

```
UPCDATA_SCALAR = GROUP UPCDATA ALL;
```

In Java, this will be repersented as a `DataBag` of `Tuple`s.  You can read more about that [here.](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/udf.html#pig-types)

It is worth keeping in mind that doing a `GROUP ALL` is really expensive so you will want to project out all the columns that aren't critical to your UDF functioning.

Comment: One more question, it's coming up as: `ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionException: Undefined parameter : UPCDATA_SCALAR` when i go to pass it in.

Comment: Try `UPCDATA_SCALAR.UPCDATA` in your method called instead of just `UPCDATA_SCALAR`.

Comment: Now pig is saying `mismatched input 'UPCDATA_SCALAR' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
` any ideas?

Comment: `TheLoaderextends LoadFunc` contructor: public `TheLoader(Tuple item_master_stream) `

Comment: `TheLoader` should be take in a `DataBag` as an argument instead of a `Tuple`.  Consider this example https://gist.github.com/hasCharles/e5c6e3dcd9c767b9377e .  If it doesn't help at all I can take a look at a gist you post later.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, right now I'm getting: `ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <file pig2.pig, line 11, column 90>  mismatched input 'UPCDATA_SCALAR' expecting RIGHT_PAREN`